# Why is shifting an affine variety keeps the degree and dimension the same?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have an affine variety $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$. 
Say I shift it by $(x_1, ..., x_n) \rightarrow (x_1 + a_1, ..., x_n + a_n)$ 
so that it becomes another affine variety $Y$ in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$.

How come the dimension and degree of $Y$ remain the same as those of $X$? 
It's intuitively clear but I wasn't really sure why... Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks you.

Comment: well isn't there an obvious isomorphism?

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης : a line is isomorphic to a conic but the degree is different, so it's important to notice that it's a linear map.